# Having problems with a Haskell script. I have this error PARSE ERROR ON INPUT "->"

Tags: haskell

I am tryng to use this example (http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HXT/Practical/Simple2) and when I try to run it always appear this PARSE ERROR ON INPUT "->"

The code where is the problem is this:

```
getTeams2 = atTag "LEAGUE" >>>
  proc l -> do
    leagName <- getAttrValue "NAME"       -< l
```

the line in especific is this:

```
 proc l -> do
```

so which problem can be??
How can i fix it?

by the way already remove all the "tabs" in the script

Comment: Do you have `{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}` set?  When I try it in GHCi I get "The last statement in a do block in an arrow command must be an expression", and if I add `return leagName` after `leagName <- getAttrValue ...`, it tells me that the expression `getAttrValue` was found where an arrow command was expected.

Comment: I running the from CMD on Windows  using this command "runhaskell example.hs"     Each time i try to running the error appears.     I have ran others examples and works.     Only have  problem with this sentence "proc x->do"            BY the way how can i get sure  i have the language arrows set?

Comment: The bit at the top of the file you linked to says `{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}`. This arrows pragma is absolutely essential to be able to run the code you show, because the `proc <something> -> <something>` is called "arrow notation" and it is *not* part of standard Haskell, but rather an extension you can enable in GHC with the arrows pragma. Make sure you also have `{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}`.

Answer (score 4):

```
proc l -> do
```

is special notation for Arrows, and you have to enable it with

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
```

at the top of your file.